# Determining $\min\{|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2 \mid z\in \mathbb{C}\}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been doing exercises on understanding the structures of given complex sets, but I'm stuck on this one.

> Find $$\min\{|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2 \mid z\in \mathbb{C}\},$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}.$

What's the correct way to tackle this kind of exercises? I've tried changing it to polar form and expanding the complex number ($z=x+iy$) but I get expressions way more complicated and I think I'm not going the right way.

Would it be correct to do $f(z)=|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2$ and differentiate this function?
That is, $f'(z)=-2a-2b+4z$.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $|z|$ is not differentiable wrt $z$.

You could think about it geometrically. Suppose you plug a $z$ into the expression $|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2$, what is this expression? It is $d_a^2+d_b^2$, where $d_a$ is the distance from $a$ to $z$ and $d_b$ is similarly interpreted. It should be easy to see that to minimise $d_a^2+d_b^2$, $z$ must be on the line segment joining $a$ and $b$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: We have $|z|^2$. That's differentiable, right?

Comment: Nope, $|z|^2$ is also not differentiable w.r.t. $z$.

Comment: @Teddy38 yes I see it now, it's the midpoint actually, but I don't know how to show it formally.

Comment: @Teddy38 Oops, I am sorry.

Comment: @Relure If you're happy with the fact that it's on the line segment, then to show that it must be the midpoint you can use some calculus or AM-GM. Suppose $x$ is a point on the line segment of length $d$, then you want to minimise $f(x)=x^2+(d-x)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Make the problem symmetric by using
$$
z=w+\frac{a+b}{2}
$$
so
$$
z-a=w+\frac{a+b}{2}-a=w-\frac{a-b}{2},\qquad
z-b=w+\frac{a+b}{2}-b=w+\frac{a-b}{2}
$$
and you have instead, with $c=(a-b)/2$,
$$
f(w)=|w-c|^2+|w+c|^2
$$
Now you can apply the parallelogram identity
$$
|x-y|^2+|x+y|^2=2|x|^2+2|y|^2
$$
which can be derived from
\begin{align}
|x-y|^2&=(x-y)(\bar{x}-\bar{y})=x\bar{x}-x\bar{y}-\bar{x}y+y\bar{y}\\
|x+y|^2&=(x+y)(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=x\bar{x}+x\bar{y}+\bar{x}y+y\bar{y}
\end{align}
Hence $f(w)=2|w|^2+2|c|^2$ and its minimum is for $w=0$.

---

By the way, this shows that the locus $|z-a|^2+|z-b|^2=k$ is a circle with center at $(a+b)/2$ and radius $\sqrt{k/2-|c|^2}$ (provided $k\ge2|c|^2$), which is easy to see also by expanding the expression with rectangular forms for $z,a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint1:** Think of it geometrically, $a \text{ and } b$ are vectors. You want a point which is closest to both.
**Hint2:** What about the midpoint of $a \text{ and } b$? Can you prove that its the minimum by expanding the objective function as $\min \ (z_x-a_x)^2 + (z_y-a_y)^2 + (z_x-b_x)^2 + (z_y-b_y)^2$?